# GKE Backup - no options in region dropdown menu

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to create a GKE Backup, no options come up for region drop down menu. Tried in chrome and edge. No errors in console or networking requests.

What regions is this feature available in? Do I need to be invited?

[image: region dropdown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage doesn't seem to work at this time. The CLI command created the backup.

```
gcloud alpha container backup-restore backup-plans create backup1 \
    --project=redacted-ai-beta \
    --location=us-east1 \
    --cluster=projects/<proj>/locations/us-east1/clusters/<cluster-name> \
    --all-namespaces \
    --include-secrets \
    --include-volume-data \
    --cron-schedule='0 0 1 * *' \
    --backup-retain-days=90
```

Answer (score 1):

Locations are synonymous with Google Cloud [regions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) in the context of the Backup for GKE service, and are confined to the regions that Backup for GKE supports. Using the Google Cloud CLI below, you can see which regions are available for your backup plans, backups, and restores:

```
gcloud alpha container backup-restore locations list \
    --project=PROJECT_ID
```

Replace `PROJECT_ID` with the ID of your Google Cloud project.

Visit the official [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/add-on/backup-for-gke/how-to/backup-plan#view_backup_locations) for more information.

Comment: That is so weird. I was entering my region us-east1-b and that was getting me no where. I ended up using the cli command, because the webpage ui was getting me nowhere, and switching to just the region without the b. `us-east1`.

Comment: I just tested the console and it works well on my end; the problem you're having could be specific to your project. You could try testing on a fresh project, and if the problem persists, I would suggest having your profile examined by support.

Comment: All works now. I'm guessing it was just a google issue. Both console and web gui are fine.